# Implementation of C++ Cast

Tags: c++, casting, unions

I was going through some code in CodeProject and came across the following code for C++  casting.

```
template <class OutputClass, class InputClass>
union horrible_union{
    OutputClass out;
    InputClass in;
};
template <class OutputClass, class InputClass>
inline OutputClass horrible_cast(const InputClass input){
    horrible_union<OutputClass, InputClass> u;
    u.in = input;
    return u.out;
}
```

Why is the cast implemented the above way. Why can't we just do a manual cast. Can someone give an example of when a normal cast wouldn't work ?

Comment: Accessing a member of a union after setting a different member is undefined behavior, so anything is better than this `horrible_union` approach.

Comment: Probably that's why it's named horrible cast. This is basically to implement some compiler specific behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This approach basically lets you get away with any cast, although it relies on undefined behavior.

A normal cast would complain when casting between unrelated types, whereas this wouldn't.

```
struct A{};
struct B{};

template <class OutputClass, class InputClass>
union horrible_union{
    OutputClass out;
    InputClass in;
};
template <class OutputClass, class InputClass>
inline OutputClass horrible_cast(const InputClass input){
    horrible_union<OutputClass, InputClass> u;
    u.in = input;
    return u.out;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    a = horrible_cast<A,B>(b);   //this compiles
    a = reinterpret_cast<A>(b);  //this doesn't
}
```

Bottom line: it's horrible, don't do it.

Comment: If you are working on a particular architecture and using a particular compiler (for some embedded system), it might be a valid approach to do type conversions that make sense only on that architecture. But it's still dangerous, I agree.

Answer (score 2):

Using a union in this way is in general roughly equivalent to a hard `reinterpret_cast` of pointers. However, that doesn't copy objects, your example does (twice even with RVO, in fact; it would be rather more efficient to have `const InputClass& input` as the argument). So you can directly operate on its result without possibly mutating the original object.

What exactly this is useful for... hm. I don't think there's any really good use case, unchecked casts should always be avoided, and as David Hammen remarked this one is actually completely undefined (though it will normally work, if used "correctly").

Comment: Maybe their shop has a policy against `reinterpret_cast`, but not this loophole.

Comment: In which case it would be even more horrible to use it: `reinterpret_cast` is dangerous, but this one is worse.

Comment: Personally, I'd much prefer seeing that `reinterpret_cast` (and perhaps having to go after a waiver if there's a rule against it) than hiding the cast like this.

Comment: @bitmask: indeed unions can be handy for fast serialisation, but not in form of such a copy-intensive template function.